# Problemas com Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hoje migrei para o Android Studio, estava usando até hoje o Eclipse + ADT para desenvolver para Android.
Então dei o `run` na aplicação e deu esse erro:

> the module cannot be android library

Não entendi o que é.

Comment: Leia isso: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959703/android-studio-cant-run-library-project

Comment: Desculpe, eu esqueci de escrever o comentário todo: Existe alguma biblioteca importada? Caso exista, leia isso: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959703/android-studio-cant-run-library-project

Answer (score 2):

Parece que você criou um projeto do tipo Library e não um projeto Android comum.

E, no caso do projeto ser do tipo Library pode estar faltando alguma coisa.

Tente criar um novo projeto e verifique os passos até a criação total. Pode ser que alguma caixa de seleção está ou foi marcada por engano.